# Drawing a Clickable Bounding Box on an imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I'm working on an face recognition in android and i'm wonder if I have an imageview can I draw a rectangle with name over it assume that I know the 4 coordinate to draw and when I clicked on the rectangle or the text it will call a function

***P/s***: If it is too complicated drawing a clickable text on an imageview would be nice too. Thank you

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if your ImageView is the background of your app, you could use a method like this:

```
public void drawRect(Graphics g){

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
g.drawText(name, x, y, paint);

}
```

I don't know how your face recognition program works but you could call this method whenever you recognize a face.

For the "clicking part", you would use a MouseListener by creating a class mouseListener implementing View.onTouchListener or you can simply add the method onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) into your main_activity.
If you go with the first choice of creating a different class (don't forget to create the object mouseListener to main and set it with setOnTouchListener), you'd have the usual onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) method and to handle the clicks, you could do something like this:

```
int x = (int) me.getX();
int y = (int) me.getY();
if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    if(x >= lowerXBoundaryOfRectangle && x <= biggerXBoundaryOfRectangle && 
          y >= lowerYBoundaryOfRectangle && y <= biggerYBoundaryOfRectangle){
//Basically, just check if x and y are in the rectangle w/ the known coordinates. 
function(); //You call the fct needed here. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i manage to draw the bounding box and the name but for the clicking part the motion event coordinates and canvas coordinates doesn't seem to match. For example when i touch the corner of rectangle the coordinate will be 200 900 but in canvas it is like 20 80. Is there a way to match coordinate between them ?

Comment: Well, you could try to find a "pattern" in these values. If you click on a point and it gives (200, 900) and you need to have (20, 80), you can try to find a number to divide the dimensions X & Y so that the values divided match what you need.

Comment: Thank you for you help. For any needed solution for that problem just use `getImageMatrix().invert(inverse)` in imageview and then use `mappoint` function to convert to canvas coordinate

Comment: I am a bit unclear what 'Graphics' as an object means? The second thing that is unclear is that the function calls itself?

Comment: Hey, the object graphics is used to draw shapes directly, here's a link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html.
The function wouldn't call itself but you would go something like: `if condition happens, then call the function`. In this case, the condition could be `if the face recognition engine recognizes a face, then call the function`. Let me know if it's still unclear.